# What is the best way to compare multiple lists with different number of parameters

Tags: tcl

I am having 4 list.

```
list1 = "hello" "hi" "bye" "lol" "rofl" "p1" "p2" "etc"
list2 = "hello" "hi" "bye" "lol" "lmao" "c1" "apple" "mango"
list3 = "hello" "hi" "bye" "lol" "rofl" "p1" "p2" "etc" "mango" "chair" "table"
list4 = "hello" "hi" "bye" "lol" "rofl" "p1" "p2" "etc" "bus" "mango" "apple" "etc"
```

I want to make a comparison among four list and need to store parameters that are matching in all list, 3 list, 2 list and not matching parameters.

What is the best way I can use to compare multiple list as there can be `n` parameters in the list and n can vary in each list.

Currently I am coding in `tcl`. But any algorithm is fine for me

Comment: I am not using C++. Any algorithm can help me

Answer (score 2):

create dictionary whose keys are words and values are integers. Pass through each list, and if the word is not present, insert it with value 1, if it is present increment its value.

To find in how many lists does a word appear, just ask the dictionary with the word as a key.

Comment: `foreach item $list1 {dict incr itemcount $item}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's some tcl:

```
set list1 {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc}
set list2 {hello hi bye lol lmao c1 apple mango}
set list3 {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc mango chair table}
set list4 {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc bus mango apple etc}

foreach var {list1 list2 list3 list4} {
    foreach elem [set $var] {
        lappend in($elem) $var
    }
}
foreach {key lists} [array get in] {
    lappend partition([llength $lists]) $key
}
```

Now:

```
% parray in
in(apple) = list2 list4
in(bus)   = list4
in(bye)   = list1 list2 list3 list4
in(c1)    = list2
in(chair) = list3
in(etc)   = list1 list3 list4 list4
in(hello) = list1 list2 list3 list4
in(hi)    = list1 list2 list3 list4
in(lmao)  = list2
in(lol)   = list1 list2 list3 list4
in(mango) = list2 list3 list4
in(p1)    = list1 list3 list4
in(p2)    = list1 list3 list4
in(rofl)  = list1 list3 list4
in(table) = list3

% parray partition
partition(1) = table lmao bus c1 chair
partition(2) = apple
partition(3) = p1 p2 mango rofl
partition(4) = hi bye hello etc lol
```

Comment: Great. Can we get the list printed like `apple` is part of which list

Comment: Sure. After the `incr count` line add `lappend in($elem) $var` so `puts "apple is in $in(apple)" `

Comment: restructured so we no longer have the "count" array.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, a solution would be:

```
<?php

// define lists (note the array_flip() calls)
$list = array();
$list[] = array_flip(array("hello", "hi", "bye", "lol", "rofl", "p1", "p2", "etc"));
$list[] = array_flip(array("hello", "hi", "bye", "lol", "lmao", "c1", "apple", "mango"));
$list[] = array_flip(array("hello", "hi", "bye", "lol", "rofl", "p1", "p2", "etc", "mango", "chair", "table"));
$list[] = array_flip(array("hello", "hi", "bye", "lol", "rofl", "p1", "p2", "etc", "bus", "mango", "apple", "etc"));

// create a union of all lists where each member is present only once
$keys = array();
for ($idx = 0; $idx<count($list); $idx++) {
    $keys = $keys+$list[$idx];
}

// iterate over the meta-list
foreach (array_keys($keys) as $key) {
    $found = array();
    for ($idx = 0; $idx<count($list); $idx++) {
        if (isset($list[$idx][$key]))
            $found[] = $idx;
    }
    printf('%s found in lists %s'.PHP_EOL, $key, join(', ', $found));
}


?>
```

Outputs:

```
hello found in lists 0, 1, 2, 3
hi found in lists 0, 1, 2, 3
bye found in lists 0, 1, 2, 3
lol found in lists 0, 1, 2, 3
rofl found in lists 0, 2, 3
p1 found in lists 0, 2, 3
p2 found in lists 0, 2, 3
etc found in lists 0, 2, 3
lmao found in lists 1
c1 found in lists 1
apple found in lists 1, 3
mango found in lists 1, 2, 3
chair found in lists 2
table found in lists 2
bus found in lists 3
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/552201)**. Note that are a few optimizations towards PHP to reduce code complexity.

- First, we put all keyword lists into a big list. We use array_flip() to have the keywords as the keys, not the values.
- Then, a list of all keywords is created by simply adding the arrays (duplicate keys overwrite, which is intended behaviour in our case).
- Then we iterate over the list of all keywords. Every keyword gets counted and the array of lists it is found in is displayed.

Comment: I think there is a confusion. I dont want elements that appear in all list. I want each element and want to find in how many list they are coming with element names. Like Hello - all, bye -all, apple - only list2 and list4, mango - list 2 and list3

Answer (score 1):

Assume this array of lists:

```
set list(1) {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc}
set list(2) {hello hi bye lol lmao c1 apple mango}
set list(3) {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc mango chair table}
set list(4) {hello hi bye lol rofl p1 p2 etc bus mango apple etc}
```

*Method 1*

```
set res {}
set allWords [lsort -unique [concat $list(1) $list(2) $list(3) $list(4)]]
foreach word $allWords {
    set in {}
    foreach i {1 2 3 4} {
        if {$word in $list($i)} {
            lappend in $i
        }
    }
    lappend res $word $in
}
```

Algorithm: create a list of all unique words. For each such word, record if it occurs in each of the lists in the array. Return an even-sized list where item 0, 2, ... is a word and item 1, 3, ... is the list numbers the word occurs in.

*Method 2*

```
set res [concat {*}[lmap word $allWords {
    list $word [lmap i {1 2 3 4} {
        if {$word in $list($i)} {
            set i
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }]
}]]
```

Essentially the same, but uses the Tcl 8.6 `lmap` command.

*Method 3*

```
unset res
foreach i {1 2 3 4} {
    foreach word $list($i) {
        dict lappend res $word $i
    }
}
```

Algorithm: for each list and word, `lappend` the list number to the item in the dictionary `res` with the key `$word`. **Note:** this solution has the drawback that if a word occurs more than once in the same list, the list number is `lappend`ed multiple times.

*Prettyprinting the result*

The `lsort -unique` is because of the weakness in Method 3: it is unnecessary for the other methods.

```
proc prettyPrint {word in} {
    set in [lsort -unique $in]
    switch [llength $in] {
        0 {}
        1 {
            puts "$word is in list $in"
        }
        2 {
            puts "$word is in list [join $in { and }]"
        }
        3 {
            puts "$word is in lists [join $in {, }]"
        }
        4 {
            puts "$word is in all lists"
        }
    }
}

foreach {w i} $res {
    prettyPrint $w $i
}
```

(The list will be printed in a different order (word insertion order) if Method 3 is used.)

```
apple is in list 2 and 4
bus is in list 4
bye is in all lists
c1 is in list 2
chair is in list 3
etc is in lists 1, 3, 4
hello is in all lists
hi is in all lists
lmao is in list 2
lol is in all lists
mango is in lists 2, 3, 4
p1 is in lists 1, 3, 4
p2 is in lists 1, 3, 4
rofl is in lists 1, 3, 4
table is in list 3
```

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [continue](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/continue.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [llength](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/llength.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm), [unset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/unset.htm)